# Como generar listado de fechas a partir de parámetros, dentro de rangos inicial y final

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cordial saludo,

Acudo a ustedes ya que requiero obtener un listado de fechas en sql server con un rango inicial y un rango final supongamos desde el 1 de febrero de 2022 al 28 febrero de 2023 pero con el siguiente filtro tipo outlook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como en la imagen el listado que se genere me traiga el tercer martes de cada 3 meses o dependiendo de lo que el usuario requiera.

Las variables se instancian desde el sql no vienen de ninguna aplicación externa, tengo este código para generar un listado que me muestre en un rango de fechas ejemplo cada dos días este numero también depende de lo que se instancie en la variable @diarioNumero

```
WITH
                        FECHAS(fecha)
                        AS
                        ( SELECT @fechInicial fecha
                            UNION ALL
                                SELECT DATEADD(day, @diarioNumero, fecha) fecha
                                FROM FECHAS
                                WHERE fecha < @fechFinal
                        )
                    select @id_spot AS '#',
                        fecha
                    from FECHAS
                    where datepart(dw, fecha) IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
                    OPTION
                    (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Para el ejercicio que requiero, la semana comienza el día domingo y lo obtengo por números con el siguiente query y el valor es 1

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW, @fechaActual) AS 'DIA SEMANA'
```

La frecuencia de meses la puedo sacar de el primer ejemplo pero no se como armar mi query, para que me genere ese listado, con el primer, segundo, tercer o cuarto día que seleccione el usuario cada tantos meses.

Lo que espero obtener es lo siguiente:

- Obtener el segundo martes de cada dos meses de febrero de 2022 a febrero de 2023

| FECHA |
| --- |
| 2022-02-01 |
| 2022-04-05 |
| 2022-06-07 |
| 2022-08-02 |
| 2022-10-04 |
| 2022-12-06 |
| 2023-02-07 |

Agradezco me puedan orientar con esta inquietud, y espero ser claro en mi pregunta.

Muchas gracias y quedo pendiente.

Cordialmente.

Comment: Hola y bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Sobre qué tabla? En qué datos? Lo haces simplemente como consulta SQL o desde una aplicación? Si es una aplicación, con qué código? Cuál es la salida esperada de la consulta? Siéntete libre de [edit] tu pregunta y añadir toda esta información

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Muchas gracias  @Alfabravo acabo de editar mi pregunta espero sea un poco mas clara y adecuada a lo que se establece en el como preguntar.. Cordial saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indagando en la web pregunte en un foro y una persona me dio la siguiente respuesta que se ajusta un poco mas a lo que estaba requiriendo. Lo asigno como respuesta correcta pero si ustedes pueden validar y dar su aval a la misma seria genial

```
DECLARE @DateStart DATE = '2022-01-01'
        , @DateEnd DATE = '2022-12-31';
        WITH DATE_RANGE
        AS (
        SELECT dateadd(day, [number], @DateStart) AS [DATE]
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [number]
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE [name] IS NULL
        ) n
        WHERE dateadd(day, [number], @DateStart) < @DateEnd
        )
        , DATE_FILTERS
        AS (
        SELECT [DATE]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY MONTH([DATE]) ORDER BY [DATE]
        ) AS WEEK_NUM
        FROM DATE_RANGE
        WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE) = 4
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM DATE_FILTERS
        WHERE WEEK_NUM = 3
        AND MONTH([DATE]) % 2 = 1
```

En este codigo se realiza  el uso de una tabla llamada master.dbo.spt_values para obtener los numeros para los dias, de igual forma realiza el incremento de los meses según la cantidad que seleccione el usuario ejemplo cada 3 meses. Posterior a esto me genera una lista la cual me arroja las fechas que se requiere como el primer martes de cada 3 meses en el rango del año 2022 de enero a diciembre.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración

Comment: Por favor, describe brevemente lo que hace el código. Puede que te haya sido útil tal como está, pero otros usuarios con un problema similar puede que se encuentren con esta respuesta y no comprendan el funcionamiento del código. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Está interesante. [Aquí](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1769/sql-server-date-function-that-determines-date-range-based-on-weekday/) alguien propone esta solución para encontrar el N-ésimo día (a partir del día actual):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DAYSEARCH(@day_name VARCHAR(9), @step_count INT, @direction smallint) 
RETURNS datetime 
AS 
BEGIN 
/* 
Returns a date based upon criteria to find a specific day-of-week  
 for a specific number of "steps" forward or backward. 
 For instance, "last Wednesday" or "two Thursdays from today". 
@day_name = day of week to find ie. Monday, Tuesday... 
@step_count = number of iterations back for a specific day: 
--------> "1 Last Monday " =  1 
--------> "3 Thursdays from now" = 3 
@direction: 
--------> -1 if Past 
--------> 1 if Future 
*/ 

 DECLARE @daysearch datetime 
 DECLARE @counter smallint 
 DECLARE @hits smallint 
 DECLARE @day_name_calc VARCHAR(9) 

 SELECT @counter = @direction 
 SELECT @hits = 0 

 WHILE @hits < @step_count 
   BEGIN 
     SELECT @day_name_calc = DATENAME(weekday , DATEADD(d, @counter, GETDATE()))  
      
     IF @day_name_calc = @day_name 
       BEGIN 
         SELECT @hits = @hits + 1 
         SELECT @daysearch = DATEADD(d, @counter, GETDATE()) 
       END 

     SELECT @counter = (@counter + (1 * @direction)) 
   END 
 RETURN @daysearch       
END
```

Ya ahí hay es que manipularlo para definir a partir de qué fecha se comienza la búsqueda y usar la misma función varias veces, moviendo la fecha inicial al día 1 de N meses en el futuro, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor para este tipo de consultas es usar una tabla calendario con todas las propiedades que puedas necesitar de cada fecha. Dejo un ejemplo de como crear una al vuelo usando CTEs, pero al ser una tabla constante puede quedarse en disco sin problema. Aquí un ejemplo de como llenarla para cien años.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS( --Generar 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --Generar 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --Generar 100 x 100 x 10 = 100,000 filas suficiente para 273 años
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b, E
),
cteFechas(fecha) AS(
    SELECT TOP (36525) --Solo generamos 100 años
        DATEADD( dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1, '20000101') fecha
    FROM E4, E
)
SELECT fecha,
    YEAR( fecha) año,
    MONTH( fecha) mes,
    DATENAME( mm, fecha) nombre_mes,
    DAY( fecha) dia,
    DATEPART( dw, fecha) dia_semana,
    DATENAME( dw, fecha) nombre_dia_semana,
    DATEPART( wk, fecha) semana,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY YEAR( fecha), MONTH( fecha), DATEPART( dw, fecha) ORDER BY fecha) dia_semana_mes
INTO #Calendario --Insertamos en una tabla (usa una permanente en vez de una temporal
FROM cteFechas;
```

Teniendo el calendario, lo más complicado es saltar los meses, pero se obtiene fácil mediante el uso de módulo.

```
DECLARE @fechInicial    date = '20220201',
        @fechFinal      date = '20230228',
        @iteracionDia   int  = 3,
        @diaSemana      int  = 3,
        @CadaNMes       int  = 3;

WITH Fechas AS(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY fecha) - 1 AS NumeroMes --Uso -1 para que inicie en el mes de la fecha inicial. 
    FROM #Calendario
    WHERE fecha >= @fechInicial
    AND   fecha <= @fechFinal
    AND   dia_semana_mes = @iteracionDia  
    AND   dia_semana     = @diaSemana     
)
SELECT fecha
FROM Fechas
WHERE NumeroMes % @CadaNMes = 0;
```